# Sass transition-delay loop?

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions, transition

I'm pushing items onto an array via AJAX and rendering them each into the DOM with a fading transition. Here is the `SASS` I've written to add a nice delay to each subsequent item:

```
  @for $i from 1 through 100 {
    .album:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
      transition-delay: $i * 0.15s;
    }
  }
```

This works as expected, however the issue is, I'm paginating the items 6 at a time. That means on the first fetch of 6, all transition as expected, however when i fetch the next 6, rather then rendering immediately, they are effected by the `transition-delay` incremental.

what 'm looking for is `SASS` logic that basically will reset the `transition-delay` incremental for every 6th instance/child. How do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively achieves the same thing, with only 6 generated rules. CSS logic, rather than SASS!

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  .album:nth-of-type(6n + #{$i}) {
     transition-delay: $i * 0.15s;
  }
}
```

Comment: great solution!